# ER model generation generates two properties for foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-relationship

I am learning MVC and I'm creating a project in which I'm Display Information like GSMarena.com phone description. I have created separate tables for Technology, Design, Display. I have used their Primary Key as Foreign key in Products Table but when I generate model in edmx file it creates properties like Design, Design1, Display, Display1 like shown in figure. I'm not able to get the reason behind this as on product create view I need all these properties for product creation.

Why is this happening and how it will effect my project?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to your comment

> ...when I generate model in edmx file it creates properties like
>   Design, Design1,...

The `Design1` property is the actual **table**. This means that from the `Product` table you can access the fields of the related `Design` table, for example you could type `myProduct.Design1.Dimensions` to access the `Dimensions` field from an instance of `Products`.

The `Design` property is the actual **numeric value** of the column `Id` of the `Design` table.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks now I get this and I will change the property Name in Products table to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

In the top part of you Product model, you've created fields for Brand, Camera, Connectivity, Design, Display, Hardware and Technology. These are not Foreign Keys

So when you add the associations between the classes, it adds Navigation Properties (which are Foreign Keys) to the table, with the next most appropriate name.

Just remove the fields from the top half of the model and rename the Navigation Properties.